# UIWebView IOS 7 mobile website

Tags: uiwebview, ios7

I have my app which was running on `ios` 6.1 perfectly. I have a `UIWebView` and I am loading a HTML5 mobile web site. It was loading perfectly. Now I have just updated my `iPad` to `ios` 7.

When I open the `UIWebView` i can see the `UIWebView` have scrollbar and the website is displayed zoomed.

Comment: if you want to fit page in view try like `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

Comment: Hello ok i will try this.. but prior to IOS 7.0 it was working perfectly .. i will try this and se what it gives :) thanks